# Коэффициенты с названием переменных по ним

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, sklearn

Вычисляю линейную регрессию.
Нужно узнать наименования коэффициентов весов.
model.coef
Не могу найти - как это сделать?

```
model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
coeff = model.coef_
print('slope:', coeff)
```

в документации смотрю https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

не нашел ответа на вопрос:

> coef_ndarray of shape (1, n_features) or (n_classes, n_features)
>
> Coefficient of the features in the decision function.
>
> coef_ is of shape (1, n_features) when the given problem is binary. In
> particular, when multi_class='multinomial', coef_ corresponds to
> outcome 1 (True) and -coef_ corresponds to outcome 0 (False).

Comment: Что вы понимаете под `"наименования коэффициентов весов"`?

Comment: @MaxU
наименования переменных, к которым относятся те или иные веса
Вес - это же по сути, как я понимаю, сила влияния на решение?
Соответственно, хочется узнать, какая из переменных насколько сильно влияет на решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок коэффициентов в `model.coef_` соответствует порядку столбцов в `X_train`.

Если `X_train` - это Pandas DataFrame to наименования коэффициентов будут соответствовать `X_train.columns`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!